# xterm copy to PRIMARY and CLIPBOARD independently

Tags: xorg, copy-paste, clipboard, xterm

I want to be able to use both selections in xterm.

I would like selecting text and using middle click to copy and paste to and from `PRIMARY`.

I would like `Ctrl+Shift+C` and `Ctrl+Shift+V` to copy and paste to and from `CLIPBOARD`.

With no changes to `Xresources`, xterm seems to use `PRIMARY` for selection and middle click copy/paste.

I've added the following to my `Xresources`:

```
XTerm.vt100.translations: #override \n\
    Ctrl Shift <Key>C: copy-selection(CLIPBOARD) \n\
    Ctrl Shift <Key>V: insert-selection(CLIPBOARD)
```

Pasting is working how I want - I can use middle click to paste `PRIMARY` and `Ctrl+Shift+V` to paste `CLIPBOARD`.
However copying isn't working - whenever I highlight text, it's being copied to both `PRIMARY` and `CLIPBOARD`.

How can I achieve what I want?

Details: Ubuntu 17.04, xterm version 324

Comment: You're probably getting caught by this line: `           <BtnUp>:select-end(SELECT, CUT_BUFFER0) \n\ `

Comment: @Tom Did you figure it out? I can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Wouldn't this only be the case if `selectToClipboard: true` and therefore `SELECT`=`CLIPBOARD`?

Comment: no - if he'd set selectToClipboard true, then both calls would go to CLIPBOARD

Comment: @ThomasDickey Okay, but why would `SELECT` be `CLIPBOARD` then? Why does the line matter, which you quoted above? :-/

Comment: His example does that, without using `SELECT`.  My comment pointed out where the program was copying to `PRIMARY`.

Comment: @ThomasDickey So as soon as a selection is being made, there is no way to circumvent it being copied to `PRIMARY`? Using an empty parameter `<BtnUp>: select-end()` did copy it as well.

Comment: @ThomasDickey Actually, adding `<BtnUp>: select-end()` to OP's code does make it not copy to `PRIMARY` at first (with selecting only), but `CTRL+SHIFT+C` still seems to copy to both `CLIPBOARD` and `PRIMARY`.

Comment: Unfortunately I never found a solution, instead I have scrapped xterm in favour of termite, where this problem doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately due to internal limitations of xterm you could achieve what you want only by choosing another terminal emulator (or by patching of xterm code).

Answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21204937 to a similar question points to the debian bug report https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=588785 where `copy-selection` was introduced as a workaround.

As far as I understand, internally xterm is able to handle just one selected region and `copy-selection` is just a means to expose the same region as several selections (both PRIMARY and CLIPBOARD).

Notice that after `copy-selection` PRIMARY and CLIPBOARD shares the same content only till another application claims its ownership. Selections become decoupled, only one of selections could still belong to xterm.

Suggestion, how to preserve PRIMARY selection hold by another application and put something to CLIPBOARD in xterm, is given in the man page, see the "Custom Key Bindings" section. However it is less convenient than [Ctrl+Shift+V] workflow. Use Shift when releasing mouse button:

```
*VT100*translations:    #override \n\
    ~Shift     <BtnUp> : select-end(PRIMARY, CUT_BUFFER0) \n\
     Shift     <BtnUp> : select-end(CLIPBOARD, CUT_BUFFER1)
```

That bug report has a hint how to keep CLIPBOARD content when new selection in xterm is started: use clipboard manager. However such applications collect all clipboard events and sometimes you need to manually clean up sensitive data. Also they could interact with e.g. vim visual selection in a quite bizarre way.

So your options:

- Just accept that xterm has single selected region
- Change you habits a bit and use different keystrokes to choose target   when finishing selection and try a clipboard manager
- Switch to a terminal emulator that behaves accordingly you expectations   (with bonus as rewrapping on window resize and ability   to switch dark/light profile at any time but loosing secure keyboard feature)